# Performing image classification with both a classifier definition file and a segmented image in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: classification, image-classification, machine-learning

I am performing object-based classifications in ArcGIS Pro in the form of two separate rounds of classifications.

In the first round, I obtained a drone image and uploaded it to GIS, I manually created training data, and then I segmented the image that I obtained. Then I used the "Image Classification" tool to classify the image with the following inputs: the raw image, the segmented image, and the training sample polygons. The classification worked great.

For the second round I created an SVM classifier file using the training samples and the image from the first round. To prepare for the classification I also segmented the second image I obtained. Then I attempted to use the "Classify Raster" tool to classify the image.

In this tool I am able to use the raw image as the input raster and the .ecd classifier file as the image classifier definition file. The goal here is to also use the segmented image that I made for the second-round image. This does not seem to be an option, however, because the "additional input raster" will not accept the segmented image as a part of the classification inputs because the attributes of the segmented image (the number of bands) do not match the attributes of the raw image.

Is there a way in which I can either transform the second-round segmented image so that it can indeed be used in the "Classify raster" tool, or could I potential utilize a different tool, or carry out the classification in python so that I can utilize the segmented image as an additional input?